# C++ Deadlock example

Tags: c++, deadlock

I'm trying to achieve simple deadlock in C++.

```
std::mutex m1;
std::mutex m2;

auto f1 = [&m1, &m2]() {
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lg1(m1);
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(10));
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lg2(m2);
    std::cout << "A";
};

auto f2 = [&m1, &m2]() {
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lg1(m2);
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(10));
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lg2(m1);
    std::cout << "B";
};

std::thread thread([&f1, &f2]() {
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; ++i)
    {
        if (i % 2 == 0)
        {
            f1();
        }
        else
        {
            f2();
        }
    }
});

thread.join();
```

If I understand correctly, I enter f1 function, lock mutex1 and wait 10 ms. In the meantime, f2 lock mutex2. Now, functions will try to lock reverse mutexes, but they are already locked. Why my program is not getting hang and it's print ABAB... and finish?

Comment: How can one thread deadlock to itself ....

Comment: When threading, you often have to contend with dumb luck. Fortunately this is not one of those times.

Comment: liliscent is right... either call f1/f2 _concurrently_ from main thread or an additional `std::thread`

Comment: Yeah, I feel so stupid now. Didnt notice it's one thread, so no data races/deadlock possibility. Now it's fixed by adding second thread.

Answer (score 8):

Just in case someone want to make a simple deadlock example:

```
std::mutex m1;
std::mutex m2;

auto f1 = [&m1, &m2]() {
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lg1(m1);
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(10));
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lg2(m2);
};

auto f2 = [&m1, &m2]() {
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lg1(m2);
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(10));
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lg2(m1);
};

std::thread thread1([&f1, &f2]() {
    f1();
});

std::thread thread2([&f1, &f2]() {
    f2();
});

thread1.join();
thread2.join();
```

Comment: Totally right. But why the extra lambdas f1 and f2? That code could simply be in the lambdas that are passed to std::thread constructors.